# Opencv contours detected discontinue

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, detection

I am detecting rectangle in an image using openCV. As in many examples, I use threshold+findContours+approxPolyDP.

As shown in image below, my problem is that the contours found by findContours don't continue, so after approxPolyDP, I can't get a rectangle...

So, do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Thank you. :)

Another question: why the contours are gray? After the thresholding, there should be only white and black, shouldn't there?

[Contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQjXG.png)

[After approxPolyDP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8BqZ.png)

Comment: becarefull in [findcontours](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) source image is modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> C++: void approxPolyDP(InputArray curve, OutputArray approxCurve,
>   double epsilon, bool closed)
>
> epsilon – Parameter specifying the approximation accuracy. This is the
>   maximum distance between the original curve and its approximation.

try  increasing epsilon

Comment: Thank you. "approxPolyDP approximate a curve or a polygon with another curve/polygon with less vertices so that the distance between them is less or equal to the specified precision. " So for a polygon, after approxPolyDP, what should we get? The vertices?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=approxpolydp)   and [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html)

Comment: approxPolyDP approximate a polygon around the contours . if epsilon is near 0 the approxPolyDP polygon become eggzaktly like polygon from contours. by increasing epsilon the approxPolyDP result's accuracy decreases ( larger epsilon the approxPolyDP will ignore the dentation in your image and gives you a rectangle) [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html#gsc.tab=0) is the perfect explanation